# Using LINQ to Entity Framework with DB2

Tags: linq-to-entities, db2, drivers, edmx

Is there an IBM Driver so we can use Linq to Entity framework to connect to DB2 and generate the DB2 entities on the desinger edmx file? Any links would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

7 is out.  You can install DB2 9.7 client in your pc to connect to any DB2 version.  You can create edmx file to DB2 8.2 database too using this 9.7 client.

While developing you might require a visual studio debugger similar to that of Scott's - Linq to SQL debug visualizer.  In that case feel free to download my RV's Linq to Entity visualizer at http://www.rajavenkatesh.com/projects.aspx

Good luck
RV

Answer (score 2):

[Yes.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/c0054118.html)

Comment: It's part of the existing .NET provider. Get the latest version of that. AFAIK, there is no separate download required for EF support.

Comment: Hi, The page that you link to has been removed

Answer (score 0):

Register yourself for closed beta program of DB2 9.7 and download the "code".  Use the image to install DB2 9.7 client and Visual studio addins.  After that you can create complete LINQ, edmx file for DB2.  But still there are some unfinished work in Beta 6.  Hopefully the final release should be fine.

Good luck